# Enumerate in Python variable positions

Tags: python, list, enumerate

i'd like to know: what's the difference between these two:

```
return "-".join([c.upper() + c.lower() * i for i,c in enumerate(txt)])
return "-".join([c.upper() + c.lower() * i for c,i in enumerate(txt)])
```

I just changed the 'i' with the 'c' and the whole code doesn't work.
Is there a simple explanation?

Comment: `enumerate` returns a number and a character in your case. It surely makes a difference whether you're trying to call `.upper()` on a number vs. a character, no?

Comment: Totally right, didn't see that at all, because only 'txt' stood there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `enumerate()` yields pairs of `(index, item)` from a given iterable.

For a string `"hello"`, it would return (formatted as a list)

```
[
  (0, 'h'),
  (1, 'e'),
  (2, 'l'),
  (3, 'l'),
  (4, 'o'),
]
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's look at the first item only, `(0, 'h')`.

If you use `i, c` to unpack this, `i`'s value will be `0`, and `c`'s value will be `'h'`, and `c.lower()` etc. makes sense, as does multiplication with the number `i`.

If you use `c, i` to unpack this, `c`'s value will be `0`, and `i`'s value will be `'h'`, and `c.lower()` no longer exists since `c` is a number and `i` is a string.

Comment: Totally got it. Thanks for the sake of simplicity!